# Why does R not auto-complete data frame variables when subsetting

Tags: r, rstudio, subset

Using the data frame mtcars on RStudio.

Say for example I want to subset `mtcars[mtcars$cyl == 4,]`

Tabbing after `mtcars$` will provide a drop down list of variable names in the data frame.

Tabbing after `mtcars[mtcars$` does not return the variable names.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it will if you add a space:

```
mtcars[ mtcars$
```

otherwise your expecting `r` to look in something called `mtcars[mtcars` not `mtcars`...

Comment: This problem seems to be fixed now in certain examples, such as the `mtcars[mtcars$` problem. it has not been fixed for longer queries such as `mtcars[mtcars$variable == mtcars$otherVariable]`

Answer (score 2):

I was going to ask the same thing. I disagree with the answer that you are expecting R to look for something called `mtcars[mtcars`, because you can't even make that without putting it all in quotes anyway, e.g.

```
test[test <- c(1,3,2) # leaves you stuck with the next line being +
```

The only way to make such an abomination is:

```
"test[test" <- c(1,3,2)
```

And once made you still cant use

```
test[test[2]
```

You still need to use quotes

```
"test[test"[2]
```

So, as far as I can tell, tabbing after `mtcars[mtcars$` failing is either a bug or has some sort of reason behind it. If there is a reason does anyone know what it is?

Comment: This has always driven me crazy to the point where for awhile I started wrapping everything in the subset with `which()` just to get it to work.